# Redux Form UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS called instantly after submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I made a login form with Redux Form and when I submit the form I make a POST request to validate the Email and Password. If the combination is incorrect I throw a new SubmissionError but this SubmissionError gets removed immediately by an `UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS` call by Redux Form.

My LoginForm component:

```
const LoginForm = ({ error, handleSubmit, authenticateUser }) => ( 
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(authenticateUser)}>
        <Field 
            name="email"
            component={RenderField}
            type="email"
            label="email"
            validate={[required, minLength(3), email]}
        />
        <Field 
            name="password"
            component={RenderField}
            type="password"
            label="password"
            validate={[required]}
        />
        {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
        <div className="login__action__container">
            <button className="login__submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <NavLink className="login__link" to="/register">Or register</NavLink>
        </div>
    </form>
)
```

The AuthenticateUser action:

```
export const authenticateUser = values => dispatch => {
return axios.post('./api/user/login', {
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password
})
.then((response) => {
     // Does stuff
})
.catch((error) => {
    throw new SubmissionError({_error: error.response.data.error})
})
```

[Image showcasing the Redux State and actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8fQs.png)

I've been bug fixing for the last few hours but still no result. Anyone with the golden tip? Thanks in advance!